# Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.execCommand]

Tags: inserthtml

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function insertHTMLCode() {
                var htmlText = '<b>HI</b>';
                try {
                    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, htmlText);
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ys_content contenteditable="true"><!-- ~Client References -->
                <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000"><strong>More information coming soon...</strong> </font> 
            <!-- ~/Client References -->
            </ys_content>
        </div>
        <input type="button" onclick="insertHTMLCode();" value="Click">
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code always throws error when I tried to insert the HTML content into the editable area in FireFox but it works fine in chrome.

My FF version: 18.0.1

Comment: Click on the editable region and then click on the button. In chrome it is adding the html <b>HI</b> at the mouse cursor position but in firefox it throws error.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div contenteditable="true">
        <ys_content ><!-- ~Client References -->
            <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000"><strong>More information coming soon...</strong> </font> 
        <!-- ~/Client References -->
        </ys_content>
    </div>
```

your wrapper div should be set as contenteditable="true"

Comment: No, the problem here was: I was using <ys_content> as like a normal HTML tag. Some browser doesn't support content editable with a custom tag. So, it was throwing error for some browsers.